# error connect ECONNREFUSED websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, p2p

Im trying to build p2p server in node.js using ws package but after running `$HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5002 PEERS=ws://localhost:5004 npm run dev` i get an error :

```
Listening on p2p port 5002
Listening on port 3002
events.js:165
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5004
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at WebSocket.finalize (/home/ris/Desktop/gj-chain/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:190:41)
    at ClientRequest._req.on (/home/ris/Desktop/gj-chain/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:639:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:395:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried reinstalling dependencies,change ports, kill processes on all ports(3002,5002,5004) but it didnt work. I believe there is some dependancy mess, im using ubuntu 16.04 node 9.11 / npm 5.6.0 version.

Comment: Well clearly _something_ is attempting to connect to port 5004. What is that?

Comment: sorry i made typo, edited question now($HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5002 PEERS=ws://localhost:5004 npm run dev).